# Rxjava newbee question around chosing an observable

Tags: android, rx-java

Have a problem that I cant seem to figure out a good solution for. I have 2 observables that I am trying observe on. During a session only 1 will spit out information while the other will throw an exception when I observe it. The data they return is the same.
Is there a simple way for me to observe both the observables and not have to wrap the exception?

```
observeA = Observable A
observeB = Observable B

Observable.<>(observeA, observeB).subscribeOn(blah)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the exception at all, you can use `merge` to observe both and `onErrorComplete` each to ignore the error:

```java
observeA = Observable A
observeB = Observable B

Observable.merge(
    observeA.onErrorComplete(), 
    observeB.onErrorComplete()
).subscribeOn(blah)
```